# laravel order by not working with paginate function

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by, pagination

when i'm trying to sort the listing of users using order by function or latest function it was not working.

```
$scan_data = Scan::where(['profile' => 'public'])->with(['user'])->whereHas('user')->orderBy('scan.created_at', 'desc')->paginate();
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: there is no error display but data are return in default sorting from database

Comment: What's the `Scan` model table called?

Comment: scan table return the data of users qr code scan data

Comment: Is the name of the table `scan` or `scans`? Also can you provide the results of this query (so we can see how it's ordered)?

Comment: thanks brother for helping it's working now there was silly mistake in my code

Comment: could you indicate where was the error? Happening the same with this piece of code: return CategoryResource::collection(Category::orderBy($this->orderBy)->paginate($this->perPage));

Comment: @DivyeshPatel I am facing the same issue can you please update the solution